# jslint-maven-plugin doesn't read jsSourceFolder and still reads default value

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, jslint

I'm trying to use jslint maven plugin. I included this in my pom file

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jslint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execute-jslint</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jslint</goal>
                        <goal>test-jslint</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceJsFolder>
                            <file>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/static/js/</file>  
                        </sourceJsFolder>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But when I run this command `maven jslint:jslint` I get this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jslint-maven-plugin:1.0.1:jslint (default-cli) on project webshop-core: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jslint-maven-plugin:1.0.1:jslint failed: basedir /home/mymac/project1/src/main/js does not exist -> [Help 1]
```

Which it still reads from the default value, according to this link http://mojo.codehaus.org/jslint-maven-plugin/jslint-mojo.html#sourceJsFolder for the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here. First, you don't need the file tag since maven knows that the string you pass in to sourceJsFolder is a path. Second, when you call `mvn jslint:jslint` the execution you are using is `default-cli` but you have not specified the `sourceJsFolder` variable for this execution. You have two options; you can move the sourceJsFolder config option outside of the execution like this:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jslint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <sourceJsFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/static/js</sourceJsFolder>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
        ...
```

Or you can specify the configuration for the `default-cli` execution also:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jslint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-cli</id>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceJsFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/static/js</sourceJsFolder>
                </configuration>
                ...
```